# PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable and PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop

Yesterday, my friend's laptop fell down on the floor. Because it is quite robust we though that it won't leave a mark. But we were wrong. Upon boot strange noises began to come out of the inside of the laptop. Then, the boot logo appeared as normal. But continuing onward, we were met with this message:

[image]

> ```
> Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 083)
> Copyright (C) 1997-2000  Intel Corporation
>
> This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
> US6,570,884, US6,115,776 and US6,327,625
>
> Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Series v2.57 (08/27/13)
> PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
> PXE-MOF: Exiting PXE ROM
> ```

Then, the BIOS error audio began bleeping like crazy and wouldn't stop until we turned the laptop off.

I think it is safe to conclude from the scratching noises that some hardware was damaged and that a technical support will be needed. I am only a bystander, but even so, **I am curious what are the possible reasons for this error.** Please, satiate my thirst for knowledge.

And just a little bonus for my friend: I am convinced that we cannot restore the computer by ourselves, but if anyone *does have* a solution, which doesn't include taking the laptop to repair (I doubt), **please tell us**. We are very grateful for your help.

Comment: We get this question *all the time.* See https://superuser.com/questions/1219285/computer-doesnt-boot-up-shows-pxe-error-and-or-operating-system-not-found

Comment: probably a failed hard drive which makes it try to boot from network.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### I am curious what are the possible reasons for this error.

This happens when you have "Boot to Network" enabled and you shouldn't see it normally if your hard disk is working.

You could try checking the BIOS to see if it can find your hard disk but I suspect your hard disk is damaged beyond repair.

> The error PXE-E61 Media Test Failure can occur at boot if all the
>   following are true:
>
> - Boot to Network (or Boot to LAN) is enabled in BIOS Setup.
> - A network cable/connection is not present.
> - Network Boot is listed in the boot order above any other boot device.
>
> To resolve this error, change the boot drive order in BIOS Setup:
>
> - Press F2 during boot to enter BIOS Setup.
> - Go to the Boot menu.
> - Set LAN or Network Boot to be the last boot option.
> - Press F10 to save and exit the BIOS Setup.

Source [PXE-E61 Media Test Failure Error](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards/000005740.html)

Comment: Though this didn't resolve the issue (we still can't boot up our laptop) it *did* give us a technical insight: BIOS is still working fine, so the system is not completely dead. A good repair will be needed, but aside from that, your answer gave us the crucial information for further investigation, hence the upvote and a tick. Thank you.

Comment: @GregorPerčič Yes, you just don't have a bootable hard disk any more. I hope you had backups ...

Comment: Fortunately we had no important data stored on the machine, so we're good (and aside from that, I'm just an intrigued bystander who wants to learn something of the situation; my friend is not so interested though...).

Comment: @GregorPerčič a "good repair" will likely be as simple as pulling the Hard Drive out and replacing it. (there should be a handly hatch to do just that without dismantling the entire thing), all you should need is a single screwdriver, (and replacement drive) and it won't invalidate your warranty. On most machines, drive replacement is expected to be user servicable.  It's probably a good time to upgrade to an SSD. Your only issue will be getting hold of your Windows Licence key, it should be on a sticker on the machine, but I know they can come off...

Comment: My friend doesn't use Windows, rather Kali Linux, which is completely free. Thank you for the info nonetheless!

Answer (score 12):

Your hard drive was likely damaged from the fall.

The strange noises are likely the failed hard drive making the [Click of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death) sound.

Since BIOS can no longer read the hard drive, it is falling back to attempt a network boot (also called [PXE boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)).  The "media test failure" means it cannot connect to a source that provides an operating system over the network.

Comment: More specifically, "media test failure" means the network cable is not present or is damaged.

Comment: @Mark Or the NIC is damaged, as is the case with my laptop.